# HTML Google Maps API is loading on desktop browser but not on Android

Tags: android, html, api, netbeans, maps

Firstly I want to share my problem with you!
1st: that is the code... I get the coordinates when I'm using the browser, but when I try to get the same information on my Android Device, it does nothing, doesn't even show errors... I'm using Netbeans 8.2 to code the HTML file.

If I try to load a map (with the Share option on google maps, the map loads just fine, but it seems it won't get my coordinates... Also, It does ask me if I want to share my location within the page.

````
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YES_I_HAVE_A_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>


<script>
function showPosition() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showMap, showError);
    } else {
        alert("Lo sentimos, su navegador no soporta geolocalizacion.");
    }
}
 
// Define callback function for successful attempt
function showMap(position) {
    // Get location data
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    
    var myOptions = {
        center: latlong,
        zoom: 16,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style:google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    }
    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("embedMap"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position:latlong, map:map, title:"¡Estas aqui!" });
}
 
// Define callback function for failed attempt
function showError(error) {
    if(error.code == 1) {
        result.innerHTML = "Decidiste no mostrar tu ubicacion :(";
    } else if(error.code == 2) {
        result.innerHTML = "Tu internet esta fallando, o el servicio GIS no esta funcionando.";
    } else if(error.code == 3) {
        result.innerHTML = "Tu solicitud para ubicarte no ha podido ser completada.";
    } else {
        result.innerHTML = "La geolocalizacion ha fallado por un error desconocido.";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="showPosition();">Mostrar mi ubicacion en Google Maps</button>
    <div id="embedMap" style="width: 600px; height: 500px;">
        
        <!--Google map will be embedded here-->
    </div>
 
    
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Where is the `initMap` function?

Comment: The only init map I have, is in the 1st script `Callback=initMap`